# About Codd's Reduction Algorithm

Tags: database, algorithm

[Codd's Algorithm](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Codd%27s+reduction+algorithm) converts an expression in tuple relational calculus to Relational Algebra. I'd like to know:

1. whether there's a standard implementation of the algorithm?
2. whether this algorithm used anywhere ? (For, the industry needs only SQL & variants, I'm not sure about database theorists in academia)
3. What's the complexity of the reduction?

Answer (score -1):

Implementing Codd's algorithm should be easy enough (*), but:

converting an expression in one language to an expression in another language requires one to know what that "other language" is.  Can you tell ?

Using the output of such a conversion is only sensible if the output of said conversion can be included in a source code, or in some other way passed onto a compiler that understands that particular language.  Do you know of a "standard" algebra-based relational data language ?

Imo, these are the two most obvious reasons why there is hardly a point in an industrial implementation.

(*) if your input is a parse tree that consists of nodes such as <universalquantification>, <existentialquantification>, <restriction>, <cartesian>, ...

Comment: Well, all I was asking for was a parser just as described. It could even be a homework/project someone has done- need not be a standard relational algebra based language at all.